# GA-4 reports coming up with (not set) and the data not capturing correctly using my custom scroll event

Tags: scroll, report, analytics

I have added a custom parameter of scroll depth on google tag manager and configured the event by adding custom event on Google Analytics-4 it worked fine at the start and have reflected on reports after 24hours.

Issue Now: I have traffic on some specific page where i want the data to be seen on my GA-4 reports and i have the configuration on GTM as shown in the attached screenshots.
I am using the following parameters on my reports as shown in the attached, here the data on my other page of website for the scroll event is not appearing.

Note:
1.Enhanced measurement for scroll is turned off.
2.Scroll event is working fine in debug mode of GA-4.
3.Checked the configurations again if I missed anything.

[GTM Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOYog.png)

[Filters for Custom tag configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCIXP.png)

As I'm a beginner, I have tried to check the steps appeared online for the reference, i want to know what I'm missing here in reports so that i could see the data that i am expecting.